# Prime factorization of 2^(16) - 1

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Trying to show the the prime factorization of $$2^{16}-1$$ without a calculator.

I know that $2^{16} - 1$ yields the prime numbers$$3*5*17*257$$ because I calculated $2^{16}-1$ on my calculator (65,535), then found that it is divisible by the prime number 5 (since the last number is 5) and so on to get my answer.

<strike>Is this possible to solve using modular arithmetic?</strike>

Using $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$
Would $a=16$ and $b=1$? After reading for the past few hours I am unable to grasp how the difference of two squares equation is applied here.

AH! I did not realize you could apply it in that way

> $2^{16}-1= (2^8-1)(2^8+1)=(2^4-1)(2^4+1)(2^8+1)=(15)(17)(257)=(5)(3)(17)(257)$

I thought that $a^2-b^2$ meant that a and b had to be squared.... Thank you so much for explaining that to me! I appreciate your help greatly. This is much more simple than I had thought.

Comment: Don't use modular arithmetic. Use $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, $2^{16}-1= (2^8-1)(2^8+1)=(2^4-1)(2^4+1)(2^8+1)=(15)(17)(257)=(5)(3)(17)(257)$

Comment: Wow. I did not know you could do that. How simple, thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome, just think of $2^{16}-1= 2^{8\times2}-1=(2^8)^2-1^2$ and then the result follows!

Comment: Exactly! As soon as you posted that I saw that I was just overthinking this problem... As I always do. I was initially trying to apply what I had learned in Discrete math & that did not work out for me. Converting to binary etc... Ugh!!